# CS50 PSET 4 "Recover". Can´t find the mistake

Tags: c, cs50

Whenever I try to compile my program, I keep getting the following error:

recover.c:39:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'jpeg'
fclose(jpeg);

I´m not entirely sure if the program is correct because I cannot even get it to run. Could anybody please help me see my mistake?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Make sure there is only 1 command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the file called "card" for reading
    FILE* card = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    //Check the card has information
    if (card == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE buffer[512];
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    char filename[8];

    //Do the following until the very end of the card
    while ((ch = fgetc(card)) != EOF)
    {

    fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card);
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            fclose(jpeg);
            FILE* jpeg = NULL;
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
            FILE *jpeg = fopen(filename, "w");
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpeg);
            i++;

        }
        // If the condition is true, open new JPEG file

        sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
        FILE* jpeg = NULL;
        FILE* jpeg = fopen(filename, "w");
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpeg);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpeg);

    }

    }
    fclose(card);




}
```

Comment: What is unclear with the error message?! You are using the name jpeg when it is not declared yet. The compiler issues messages specially for you.

Comment: The line `fclose(jpeg);` appears before the line `FILE* jpeg = NULL;`, so the variable `jpeg` is not declared yet when you first use it. This is not allowed in C. You must first declare a variable before using it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because `jpeg` is being created after `fclose(jpeg);`

Try to put `FILE* jpeg = NULL;` before `fclose(jpeg);`

So your code look like this:

```c
...
if (i != 0)
{
    FILE *jpeg = NULL;
    fclose(jpeg);
    sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
    *jpeg = fopen(filename, "w");
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpeg);
    i++;
}
...
```

Do note that bellow `sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);` you are creating `jpeg` again, so remove the `FILE` part.

Also you didn't include the lib `cs50.h` in your header, this can create some problems.